# On github, what does build status mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

Especially if a rails gem, for example, has "failing" as its build status?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're talking about is the build status image provided by `travis-ci` (or maybe any `jenkins` setup, I don't know). It is used to inform users of the build status of the master branch of the repository, allowing them to know if it safe to refer to the repository on their Gemfile without having to setup and launch the test suite.

Comment: how do you check for the latest non-failing build?

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature of the Travis Continuous Integration service.

http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/status-images/

Answer (score 2):

It is the result of a build scheduler able to communicate back to GitHub the build result, through the [Commit Status API](https://github.com/blog/1227-commit-status-api), using the [Repo Statuses API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/).

And starting April 26th 2013, you can see that same [build status](https://github.com/blog/1227-commit-status-api) on your [GitHub repo **branch** page](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/):

[image: build status on GitHub repo branches]

Starting April 30th, 2013, the [API endpoint for commit statuses](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#list-statuses-for-a-specific-ref) has been extended to allow branch **and tag names, as well as commit SHAs**.